# How to use a cookie from interceptor as env variable?

Tags: javascript, postman, interceptor

I'm trying to use a cookie from interceptor as env variable to use it as Bearer token but all solutions I got tell me to use them from response and there is no cookie there, I need to set the cookie BEFORE the request is made (because is the token), the code I had is the following:

```
var my_cookie = pm.cookies.get("cookie1");
pm.globals.set("gateway_token", my_cookie);
```

But this code is trying to retrieve after the request is made (and there is none in my endpoint), how can I get it from interceptor?